# Mongodb: extract element from object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to extract the element `cod_modalidadeoperacao` from the `obj_modalidadeoperacao` in the following collection:

```
{
    "id_bdt" : "AMBA",
    "nom_curto" : "BALBINA             ",
    "obj_modalidadeoperacao" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6040e1feb97a0fde48b8f79c"),
        "id_bdt" : "7",
        "mrid_bdt" : "173355d7-e7e7-4727-b526-bc687b117bdc",
        "nom_modalidadeoperacao" : "USINA CUJA OPERAÇÃO IMPACTA A REDE DE OPERAÇÃO",
        "cod_modalidadeoperacao" : "Tipo I"
    }
}
{
    "id_bdt" : "APCN",
    "nom_curto" : "US.COA.NUNES        ",
    "obj_modalidadeoperacao" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6040e1feb97a0fde48b8f79c"),
        "id_bdt" : "7",
        "mrid_bdt" : "173355d7-e7e7-4727-b526-bc687b117bdc",
        "nom_modalidadeoperacao" : "USINA CUJA OPERAÇÃO IMPACTA A REDE DE OPERAÇÃO",
        "cod_modalidadeoperacao" : "Tipo I"
    }
}
```

When I use this filter:

```
db.getCollection("c_usina").find({}, {id_bdt : 1, nom_curto : 1, "obj_modalidadeoperacao.cod_modalidadeoperacao" : 1 })
```

I get this:

```
{
    "id_bdt" : "AMBA",
    "nom_curto" : "BALBINA             ",
    "obj_modalidadeoperacao" : {
        "cod_modalidadeoperacao" : "Tipo I"
    }
}
{
    "id_bdt" : "APCN",
    "nom_curto" : "US.COA.NUNES        ",
    "obj_modalidadeoperacao" : {
        "cod_modalidadeoperacao" : "Tipo I"
    }
}
```

What I would like to get is this:

```
{
    "id_bdt" : "AMBA",
    "nom_curto" : "BALBINA             ",
    "cod_modalidadeoperacao" : "Tipo I"
}
{
    "id_bdt" : "APCN",
    "nom_curto" : "US.COA.NUNES        ",
    "cod_modalidadeoperacao" : "Tipo I"
}
```

What do I need to change in the find command to do this?

Comment: Why do you need it in this certain way? Are you sure you can't solve your problem by using it the way it gives you?

Answer (score 0):

Projection options of query works similar to the aggregation [$projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage

So you can do something like this:

```
db.getCollection("c_usina").find({}, {
  id_bdt: 1,
  nom_curto: 1,
  cod_modalidadeoperacao: "$obj_modalidadeoperacao.cod_modalidadeoperacao" // project a field with an expression
})
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The field didn't show with this solution though.
`{
    "id_bdt" : "AMBA",
    "nom_curto" : "BALBINA             "
}
{
    "id_bdt" : "APCN",
    "nom_curto" : "US.COA.NUNES        "
}
`
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.15

Comment: I tested on 6.0 and 4.4 and it worked. Maybe for 3.x you need to use [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate) with [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)